# Cannot get alert to work when clicking image using React

Tags: reactjs

I am having an issue where I want an alert to popup when I click on an image with React.  Unfortunately I cannot figure out why this does not work on when I click on the image.  Can someone please help me with this issue?

```
  state = {
    cards
  }

  handleClick = () => {

    alert("I have been clicked");
    console.log("clicked")
  }

  render = () => {

    return (
      <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar /> 
        <ImageContainer>
          {this.state.cards.map(card => {
            return <ImageCard handleClick = {this.handleClick} image={card.image}  />
          })};
        </ImageContainer>

      </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }

}
```

Here is what I have for ImageCard:

```
export const ImageCard = (props) => (
  <Col lg={4}>
  <Card>
  <Card.Img variant="top" src={props.image} />    
  </Card>
  </Col>
);
```

Comment: What is `ImageCard`? Does it have a `handleClick` prop?

Comment: I guess it should be `onClick` by convention (however the method can be named as `handleClick` to avoid confusion). Also you are missing the required `key` prop in `<ImageCard />`.

Comment: ImageCard is a component which I created for the cards.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a prop called `handleClick` to your `<ImageCard />` component. Take a look at your `<ImageCard />`. Once it receives that prop it does nothing with it so it is not being used for an `onClick` in any way. Try renaming the prop from `handelClick` to `onClick`, or pass the `handeClick` down to the `<Card />` or `<Col />` component within `<ImageCard />`.